Automatically turn screen to fullscreen
I'm making an autoplay system, and I need to start the video in autoplay. The problem is that the browser blocks anyway, as there was no interaction with the user. I'm using planda player api, vue-youtube and vue-vimeo-play. Does anyone know of a way to do this without the browser blocking?
I've tried almost all the simpler ways, and even some more advanced ones. Nothing went right.

The only thing you can possibly do as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide, is to autoplay a video while it is muted. Also your title is asking about auto fullscreen but the question is about autoplay.
